# Getting plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, matplotlib

```
def get_plot(x_plot, y_plot, column_span, title, x_axis_1, y_axis_1,
            x_axis_2 = None, x_axis_3 = None,
            y_axis_2 = None, y_axis_3 = None,
            label_1 = None, label_2 = None, label_3 = None):
    ax[x_plot][y_plot] = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (x_plot, y_plot), colspan = column_span)
    if label_1 is None:
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].plot(x_axis_1, y_axis_1, linewidth = 2, color = ([0.37, 0.23, 0.37]), marker = 'o')
    else:
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].plot(x_axis_1, y_axis_1, linewidth = 2, color = ([0.37, 0.23, 0.37]), label = label_1, marker = 'o')

    if x_axis_2 is not None and  y_axis_2 is not None and label_2 is not None:
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].plot(x_axis_2, y_axis_2, linewidth = 2, color = ([0.44, 0.64, 0.69]), label = label_2, marker = 'o')
        if title == ' sterillite' or title == 'Fennel seeds':
            ax[x_plot][y_plot].set_ylim(0, 100)
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].legend()

    if x_axis_3 is not None and  y_axis_3 is not None and label_3 is not None:
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].plot(x_axis_3, y_axis_3, linewidth = 2, color = ([0.68, 0.74, 0.22]), label = label_3, marker = 'o')
        ax[x_plot][y_plot].legend()

    ax[x_plot][y_plot].set_xlim(xmin = 0.0)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 8)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 8)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].set_axisbelow(True)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].yaxis.grid(True)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].xaxis.grid(False)
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_y_tick_suffix))
    ax[x_plot][y_plot].set_title(title, fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold")
```

The above code is working but it is way too much complex to understand. Can someone suggest me an alternate way of writing it? I am new to the python can someone please help.

Comment: explain what you want

Comment: @DejanMarić The above code is working but it is way too much complex to understand. Can someone suggest me an alternate way of writing it? I am new to the python can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just two suggestions:

Use a variable to hold `ax[x_plot][y_plot]`, so you don't need to repeat that everytime. e.g.::

```
a = ax[x_plot][y_plot] = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (x_plot, y_plot), colspan = column_span)
a.plot(...)
#etc.
```

Instead of `x_axis_1`, and so on, make a structure to hold plot data and give it as list:

```
from collections import namedtuple
PlotData = namedtuple('PlotData', 'x_axis y_axis label color')

# ...

plotdata_list = [Plotdata(x1, y1, label1, color21), ...]
get_plot(x_axis, y_axis, column_span, title, plotdata_list)
```

... and use a loop to make the plots.

Code (untested):

```
def get_plot(x_plot, y_plot, column_span, title, plotdata_list):
    a = ax[x_plot][y_plot] = plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (x_plot, y_plot), colspan = column_span)

    for data in plotdata_list:
        kwargs = {}
        if data.label:
            kwargs['label'] = data.label
        a.plot(data.x_axis, data.y_axis, linewidth=2, color=data.color, marker='o', **kwargs)

    if len(plotdata_list) > 1:
        if title == ' sterillite' or title == 'Fennel seeds':
            a.set_ylim(0, 100)
        a.legend()

    a.set_xlim(xmin = 0.0)
    a.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 8)
    a.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 8)
    a.set_axisbelow(True)
    a.yaxis.grid(True)
    a.xaxis.grid(False)
    a.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_y_tick_suffix))
    a.set_title(title, fontsize = 10, fontweight = "bold")
```

Call like this (following your comment):

```
get_plot(0, 0, column_span=2, title='hp_accessories', 
        plotdata_list=[
            # arguments: x, y, label, color
            PlotData(hp_laser_ts, hp_laser, 'Lasers', [0.37, 0.23, 0.37]),
            PlotData(hp_keyboard_ts, hp_keyboard, 'Keyboards', [0.44, 0.64, 0.69]),
            PlotData(hp_mouse_ts, hp_mouse, 'Mice', [0.68, 0.64, 0.22]),
        ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am getting consfuse how can I call this function.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can I call this function as per your code
`get_plot(x_plot=0,y_plot=0,col=2,m1=hp_laser_ts,m2=hp_keyboard_ts,m3=hp_mouse_ts,n1=hp_laser,n2=hp_keyboard,n3=hp_mouse, lab1='Current', lab2='Last year',lab3='2 years ago',title='hp_accessories')
     
get_plot(x_plot=0,y_plot=2,col=1,title='hp_cpu, m1=hp_cpu_ts,n1=hp_cpu_datapoints)

get_plot(m=2,n=2,col=1,title='hp_motherboard',m1=hp_processor_ts, m2=hp_ram_ts,n1=hp_processor,n2=hp_ram,lab1='processor',lab2='ram')`

Comment: any thoughts on the above I really apprecaite that?

Comment: see added call example